# How does one input a subrange-dependent Jacobian using minimize from scipy.optimizate given that the objective function returns a sum over a range?

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, parameter-passing, mathematical-optimization, chaining

Suppose one is trying to minimize a [chi square function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzDxV.gif) for given expectation values per bin and observed counts per bin. In python syntax, (assuming equal lengths of lists for expectation values and observed counts), the chi square function is

```
obs[i] are the observed counts in the i-th bin
exp[i] are the expectation values of the i-th bin (obtained by integrating distribution function over bin bounds)
chisquare = sum([( (obs[i] - exp[i])**2 / exp[i] ) for i in range(len(obs))])
```

On paper, I know how to calculate the partial derivatives of chi square (wrt to observed counts per bin and wrt to expectation values per bin) to compute a Jacobian.

```
jaco = [( 2 * (obs[i] - 1) / exp[i] ), ( (exp[i]**2 - obs[i]**2)/exp[i] )]
```

If the i-th bin is being considered, then the terms of all other bins in the Jacobian are all zero.

According to [the SCIPY docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html#scipy.optimize.minimize),

> jac : bool or callable, optional
>   Jacobian (gradient) of objective function. Only for CG, BFGS, Newton-CG, L-BFGS-B, TNC, SLSQP, dogleg, trust-ncg. If jac is a Boolean and is True, fun is assumed to return the gradient along with the objective function. If False, the gradient will be estimated numerically. jac can also be a callable returning the gradient of the objective. In this case, it must accept the same arguments as fun.

Without the Jacobian, my code is

```
from scipy.stats import chisquare
def argmin( args ):
    #argmin is the argument that is minimized by the function defined below
    # arg1 = mu
    # arg2 = sigma
    obsperbin = countperbin( numbins = numbins ) # pre-defined function (not shown)
    expperbin = expectperbin( numbins , args ) # pre-defined function (not shown)
    return chisquare(obsperbin, expperbin)

from scipy.optimize import minimize
def miniz( ):
    parameterguess = initial_params( ) # pre-defined function (not shown) that returns [mu, sigma]
    # [mu, sigma] of distribution used to generate initial guess of chi square value
    # looks for optimized values of [mu, sigma] that minimize chi square

    bnds = ((0.01, 10), (0.01, 1)) # ((bounds of mu), (bounds of sigma))
    globmin = minimize( argmin , parameterguess , method = 'L-BFGS-B', bounds = bnds, jac = jaco)

res = miniz()
print(res)
```

My trouble is that the Jacobian is bin-dependent and the chi square value is a sum over all of the bins. Does this mean that the Jacobian that should be an argument in the minimizing function should be the sum of each Jacobian over each bin? Or perhaps an array for each iteration? How am I to input the Jacobian as an argument in the minimizing function?

Comment: For a start, I think you have your chi-square gradient wrong. You must **not** differentiate with respect to observed and expected counts, but rather with respect to `mu` and `sigma`. The observed part stays constant, it is the expected part that can vary (via its dependency on mu and sigma) in the minimization.

Comment: I think my method still applies but please correct me if I'm wrong. The object  being minimized is ideally chi square, which depends upon constant observed and variable expected counts per bin. By making the expected counts per bin dependent upon args `mu` and `sigma`, my code implicitly passes them through when finding the expected counts per bin that minimizes chi square. Even though the observed counts per bin are constant, expanding out the squared difference of the chi square formula yields an expression `f`. Coeffs in the partial derivatives of `f` include observed counts of degree 0-2.

Comment: Sure, the partial derivatives with respect to mu and sigma include an `o` (observed count) term. What I'm saying is that you need to differentiate with respect to the variables that you are optimizing over (mu, sigma), not `o` and `e` (expected count). The partial derivative with respect to `o` is absolutely meaningless in this context.

Comment: Look at it this way: the `minimize` routine works by passing different (mu, lambda) points to your `argmin` function and then varies (mu, lambda) such that the function value of `argmin` becomes as small as possible. If you want to use a gradient based optimizer and also supply the gradient function yourself, then your function will be called with the **exact same** (mu, lambda) point that is passed to `argmin` and the minimizer expects the slopes in the `mu` and `sigma` directions at that point as the return value of your user-provided `bac` function. Return anything else and you are lost.

Comment: That makes sense. I'll try to implement this and will update when it's better. Thanks again!